# Can I initialize std::unique_ptr of array without default initialization ( I want just let it have dummy value )

Tags: c++, initialization, c++17, c++14, unique-ptr

Can I initialize std::unique_ptr of array without default initialization ( I want just let it have dummy value )
I'm trying to use unique_ptr of array for preventing memory leak.
but It looks always initializing values with 0 ( look "movups  XMMWORD PTR [rax+48], xmm0" )
I don't need this. I just want vector2 have dummy value.
Can I do this??

```
#include <memory>

struct Vector2
{
    float x, y;
};

struct A
{
    std::unique_ptr<Vector2[]> vector2;
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    a.vector2 = std::make_unique<Vector2[]>(10);
}


    sub     rsp, 40                             ; 00000028H
    mov     QWORD PTR a$[rsp], 0
    mov     ecx, 80                             ; 00000050H
    call    void * operator new[](unsigned __int64)               ; operator new[]
    test    rax, rax
    je      SHORT $LN15@main
    xorps   xmm0, xmm0
    movups  XMMWORD PTR [rax], xmm0
    movups  XMMWORD PTR [rax+16], xmm0
    movups  XMMWORD PTR [rax+32], xmm0
    movups  XMMWORD PTR [rax+48], xmm0
    movups  XMMWORD PTR [rax+64], xmm0
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`make_unique` performs value-initialization on the array. You can use [`make_unique_for_overwrite`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique) (since C++20) instead, which performs default-initialization.

```
a.vector2 = std::make_unique_for_overwrite<Vector2[]>(10);
```

Before C++20, you can `new` the array by yourself.

```
a.vector2 = std::unique_ptr<Vector2[]>(new Vector2[10]);
// or
a.vector2.reset(new Vector2[10]);
```